# How to Store Elements as Objects not HTML-Elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an HTML table I have a row like this:

```
<tr class="csp-criterion">
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td><input type="number"></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">7</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to get every element with the class `csp-matrix-value`, to later access the text inside of this element. So I store the elements in a variable like this:

```
$ratingTds = $('tr').children('td.csp-matrix-value');
```

I was expecting I could later do something like this:

```
$ratingTds.each().text();
```

But that renders an error. I think the elements are not being stored as objects, but as plain HTML elements. But I'm really not sure, what's going on here.

Comment: You can: `$ratingTds.text("Hello");` or one by one `$ratingTds.each((i,td) => console.log($(td).text()))`

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Did you check the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) docs once on how to use each?

Comment: Yes, but even writing it out as a function gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`.each()`**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) accepts a function as parameter:

```js
$ratingTds = $('tr').children('td.csp-matrix-value');
$ratingTds.each((_, el) => console.log($(el).text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="csp-criterion">
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td><input type="number"></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="csp-matrix-value">7</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually solved my problem. The syntax you used is new to me, but it works!

Comment: @TheKidsWantDjent, the syntax is arrow function syntax, though you can use normal function syntax:)